# C# Multiple Simultaneous System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I have a C# class, MyCommand, that is run using a backgroundWorker and thread pool. MyCommand executes a command line executable using the Process class. The instances of MyCommand, each in their own thread, are running in a serial fashion instead of parallel. I'm just wondering if the execution of Process.Start() in MyCommand is blocking the other threads.

```
Process pProcess = new Process(); 
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "decrypt.exe"; 
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "list of args" ;
pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
pProcess.Start(); 
string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 
pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Are these long running processes that could throw a fatal exception? If not, I wouldn't go with a process. Check out the Task Parallel Library on MSDN.

Comment: There's something wrong with your code. However, we can't tell what's wrong without *seeing* your code.

Comment: In the process, I run an executable that decrypts a file, so each thread decrypts a different file. The decryption program is completing. I am printing out its output. The decryption program is compiled from c++ sources. But based on other responses, it seems that it may have something to do with the program itself.

So in my Form I start the background worker via a button click which takes execution to DoWork method. In this method I launch the thread using thread pool using the example provided in the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: In MyCommand I have something like this:

Process pProcess = new Process();
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "decrypt.exe";
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ...
pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pProcess.Start();
string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
pProcess.WaitForExit();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Process.Start doesn't block. However the application you're starting might. For example if it used a mutex to make sure only one instance of was running at one time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: no, starting a process doesn't block other threads.